# How to do object restructuring in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is there a way to do this in a single statement?

```
var {a:c, b} = {a:2, b:3}; // es6 destructuring
var d = {b, c} // es6 shorthand properties
```

I want to transform `{a:2, b:3}` to `{b:3, c:2}` in a single statement.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to go for

Answer (score 10):

Don't use destructuring and shorthand properties, just construct your literal like you want:

```
var input = {a:2, b:3};

var d = {b:input.b, c:input.a}; // single statement
```

Alternatively use an immediately invoked arrow function (IIAF):

```
var d = (({a:c, b}) => ({b, c}))(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to transform {a:2, b:3} to {b:3, c:2} in a single statement.

You just need to swap the properties:

```
const {b, a:c} = {a:2, b:3}
b // 3
c // 2
```